# Symfony2: How can I list table elements in a FormChoice, separating them by some property

Tags: list, symfony, categories

Is there any way to fetch objets from the DB and list them by Category? I have a table Artist which have a Genre and each Genre have a Category, so when I'm choosing Genre at new Artist creation I would like to see them separately by each one Category. I recall that in previous versions you could do something like:

```
    $this->widgetSchema['genre_id'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
                        'choices' => array('-- Select --',
'-- Category1 --'=>Doctrine_Core::getTable('Genre')->getGenres('Category1')),
'-- Category2 --'=>Doctrine_Core::getTable('Genre')->getGenres('Category2')),
                        'multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false
                    ));
```

And the result was a drop down with 'CategoryX' in bold, followed by respectively genres.

After a deep search all I've found is:

```
->add('group', 'entity', array(
                   'class' => 'Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\Group',
                   'label'=>'Group:',
                   'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                       return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                                 ->... // whatever you want to do
                       }
                    ))
```

I think that is what I need, but have no idea on how to adapt it to what I'm looking for.

Many thanks.